# bash awk передача внешней переменной в шаблон

Tags: регулярные-выражения, bash, shell, awk

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему у awk не работает передача внешней переменной в шаблон.
Пример скрипта:

```
#/bin/sh

PROTO="tcp"

LINES=(`sudo /sbin/iptables --numeric --line-numbers --list INPUT | awk -v prt=$PROTO '/prt/ {print $1}'`)

echo ${LINES[@]}
```

Вывод: пустой массив.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в указании шаблона, корректная строка:

```
LINES=(`sudo /sbin/iptables --numeric --line-numbers --list INPUT | awk -v prt=$PROTO '$0 ~ prt {print $1}'`)
```